# Ubuntu 19.04 and WebKitGtk

Tags: 19.04, gtk3, webkit

I'm trying to install WebKitGtk on Ubuntu 19.04, and I'm not having any luck.  The instructions I found on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WebKit says "If your ./autogen.sh command runs without any hitches you are ready to compile WebKit. Issue the following command in your terminal and grab a beer:".  Well, it doesn't run because there's no file there by that name, and there are no suggestions aside from grabbing a beer upon success.  Can anyone tell me if WebKitGtk is compatible with 19.04, and if so, what is the preferred (easy) way to install it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What is wrong with installation of it as `libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev` binary package built from [`webkit2gtk`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/disco/webkit2gtk) source?

Comment: See https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=WebKitGtk&searchon=names

Comment: For question 1, I'm just trying to get up and running with WebKit so I can embed a browser in my GTK3 application.  I did "sudo apt-get install libwebkit2gtk-4.0-dev and it appeared to install, but I still get an include error on #include <webkit2/webkit2.h>.  Can you tell me what my include/lib paths should look like.  Also, thank you very much for your help.  As for #2, nothing in that page specifically mentioned disco dingo, so I went with suggestion #1.